# What is a strategy for SEO since URL Rewriting in Lightning Community is not possible?

Tags: community, lightning-community, urlrewriter

The [Salesforce Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo_faq.htm) states that URL Rewriting is not supported in Lightning Communities:

> **Is URL rewriting for creating custom vanity URLs supported?**
>
> No, URL rewriting isn’t supported for template-based communities.

In a Visualforce community we would use an URLRewiriter to translate friendly URLs that are useful for SEO into parametrized URLs that are useful for development. For example:

```
/category1/subcategory1 -> /customCategoryCommunityPage?category=123&subcategory=456
```

It is possible to do [something for some detail pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo_faq.htm):

```
https://mycommunity.com/s/account/001R0000002NzuaIAC/aw-computing.
```

However, that only addresses detail pages.

Are Friendly URLs possible at all in Lightning Communities? If not, what, if anything, can be done?

Comment: [Site redirects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_redirects.htm&type=5) do work in a community. For a few vanity URLs, it's a good option. A scalable solution that addresses more dynamic rewriting schemes via query params or other HTTP request properties, it is not.

Comment: Thanks @identigral. That takes me back to my Site.com dev days of 7 years ago (time flies). [Site.com using Alias Redirects](http://peterknolle.com/site-com-data-and-content-strategies/), but as you stated it doesn't scale.